# Is there a way to automatically add all team members to everybody's contacts?

Tags: google-workspace, google-contacts

I have just newly setup Google Apps. But as it is now, everybody in the team needs to add the contacts to everybody else in the team (manually). Isn't there a way to add these automatically?

So basically what I would need is that when a new user is created for Google Apps, this user will be added to everybody's contact list. Ideally the same should apply for groups.

I saw that there is some support for LDAP servers to manage contacts, but I think this could be an overkill.

Does Google Apps provide another, more direct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Control Panel, under contacts Settings > ENABLE CONTACT SHARING

[image: contact sharing]

What you also can do is to import/export contacts. But I'm not quite sure if this is what you need..

Comment: I had that option enabled already, but it was until recently that the contacts have appeared under "Directory". I am not sure if this was due to a very slow synchronization or because of something else I've changed. Surely though contact sharing needs to be enabled. So will accept this as an answer.